# How to model in r first time

Tags: r, model

I have my function in R program:

I want to plot a dose response function

For any values of : X, c ,E , HS,

I'm new to R, so I am asking for help (and indulgence is my first question on this forum)

Comment: *"I want to create a model using this function"* I'm not sure what this means. Do you want to *fit* a model to data? If so, I recommend taking a look at [`drc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/index.html) which provides methods to fit various dose-response models to data. On a side note: The expression "gamma(V(c), σ^2)" doesn't make sense (mathematically). Assuming by "gamma" you mean the Gamma distribution, the distribution is usually characterised by two parameters alpha and beta; "V(c)" seems to refer to your *function*, and σ^2 usually refers to the variance of a normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I meant Gamma distribution and variances for it. I want to do my first own model in R

Comment: *”I want to do my first model in R”* Again what does that mean? Do you want to fit a model to data? Or do you want to visualise/plot a dose response function?

Comment: Sorry for being not very precise, definitely the second I want to plot a dose response function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, it's useful to recognise that `V(c, E, HS, EC_50)` has the form of a 3-parameter log-logistic dose-response function, where

1. `EC_50` is the log-transformed EC50 dose,
2. `HS` is the Hill slope or slope factor,
3. `E` is the lower asymptotic response limit,

and `c` is the log-transformed dose.

Note that `exp^(...)` is not valid R syntax; fixing this, we get the following form for `V(c, E, HS, EC_50)`

```r
V <- function(c, E, HS, EC_50) E + (1 - E) / (1 + exp(HS * (c - EC_50)))
```

We can now define some (sensible) values for the three parameters

```r
HS <- 1
log_EC50 <- log(1e-3)
E <- 0
```

and then calculate the response for a range of (log-transformed dose) values `c`. We store values in a `data.frame`.

```r
log_c <- seq(-12, 0, by = 0.1)
df <- data.frame(log_c = log_c, response = V(log_c, E, HS, log_EC50))
```

We can now plot the `response` as a function of `log_c`; I am using `ggplot2` here to do the plotting.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(log_c, response)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]